# Page is not loading after some multiple loops

Tags: php, loops

I am working on Flight portal. Lets assume that there are two pages (Search.php, Result.php).

In search page we will select the source,destination,date of journey..etc.(Now we will click on search button)

After clicking on the search button page will redirect to Result.php and there we will display the results.

Here before displaying the results on the page i am trying to insert those result in the database as below.

```
$q=0;
    foreach($array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'] as $main)
    {
        $f1=$basefare[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['ActualBaseFare'];

        $f10=$octax[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['ocTax'];

        $f11=$pcom[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['TPartnerCommission'];

        $f12=$tsdiscount[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['TSdiscount'];

        $f2=$tax[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['Tax'];

        $f3=$stax[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['STax'];

        $f4=$tcharge[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['TCharge'];

        $f5=$scharge[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['SCharge'];

        $f6=$tdiscount[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['TDiscount'];

        $f7=$tmarkup[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['TMarkup'];

        $f8=$fid[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['id'];

        $f9=$fkey[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['key'];

        $ft=$totalfare[$q]=($basefare[$q]+$tax[$q]+$stax[$q]+$scharge[$q])-$tdiscount[$q];

        $a1=$abasefare[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['FareBreakup']['FareAry']['Fare']['BaseFare'];

        $a2=$atax[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['FareBreakup']['FareAry']['Fare']['Tax'];

        if($child>0 || $infant>0)
        {
        $a1=$abasefare[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['FareBreakup']['FareAry']['Fare'][0]['BaseFare'];

        $a2=$atax[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['FareBreakup']['FareAry']['Fare'][0]['Tax'];
        }

        if($child>0)
        {
        $c1=$cbasefare[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['FareBreakup']['FareAry']['Fare'][1]['BaseFare'];

        $c2=$ctax[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['FareBreakup']['FareAry']['Fare'][1]['Tax'];
        }

        if($child>0)
        {
        $i1=$ibasefare[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['FareBreakup']['FareAry']['Fare'][2]['BaseFare'];

        $i2=$itax[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['FareBreakup']['FareAry']['Fare'][2]['Tax'];
        }

        if($child==0)
        {
        $i1=$ibasefare[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['FareBreakup']['FareAry']['Fare'][1]['BaseFare'];

        $i2=$itax[$q]=$array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['FareDetails']['FareBreakup']['FareAry']['Fare'][1]['Tax'];
        }

    $s=0;
    foreach($array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['onward']['FlightSegments']['FlightSegment'] as $array)
    {
            $z1=$flightnumber[$q][$s]=$array['FlightNumber'];
            $z2=$airlinename[$q][$s]=$array['OperatingAirlineName'];
            $z3=$airlineflightnumber[$q][$s]=$array['OperatingAirlineFlightNumber'];
            $z4=$airlinecode[$q][$s]=$array['OperatingAirlineCode'];
            $z5=$departureloc[$q][$s]=$array['DepartureAirportName'];
            $z6=$departurecode[$q][$s]=$array['DepartureAirportCode'];
            $z7=$arrivalloc[$q][$s]=$array['ArrivalAirportName'];
            $z8=$arrivalcode[$q][$s]=$array['ArrivalAirportCode'];
            $z9=$departuretime[$q][$s]=$array['DepartureDateTime'];
            $z10=$arrivaltime[$q][$s]=$array['ArrivalDateTime'];
            $z11=$airequiptype[$q][$s]=$array['AirEquipType'];
            $z12=$linksell[$q][$s]=$array['LinkSellAgrmnt'];
            $z13=$conx[$q][$s]=$array['Conx'];
            $z14=$airpchg[$q][$s]=$array['AirpChg'];
            $z15=$insideavailoption[$q][$s]=$array['InsideAvailOption'];
            $z16=$gentrafrestriction[$q][$s]=$array['GenTrafRestriction'];
            $z17=$DaysOperates[$q][$s]=$array['DaysOperates'];

            $z30=$enddate[$q][$s]=$array['EndDt'];      
            $z31=$oaf[$q][$s]=$array['OperatingAirlineFlightNumber'];       
            $z32=$nstops[$q][$s]=$array['NumStops'];        
            $z18=$JrnyTm[$q][$s]=$array['JrnyTm'];      
            $z19=$StartTerminal[$q][$s]=$array['StartTerminal'];        
            $z20=$EndTerminal[$q][$s]=$array['EndTerminal'];        
            $z21=$FltTm[$q][$s]=$array['FltTm'];        
            $z22=$LSAInd[$q][$s]=$array['LSAInd'];      
            $z23=$Mile[$q][$s]=$array['Mile'];

            $z24=$avail[$q][$s]=$array['BookingClass']['Availability'];     
            $z29=$bic[$q][$s]=$array['BookingClass']['BIC'];        
            $z25=$bookingclass[$q][$s]=$array['BookingClassFare']['bookingclass'];      
            $z26=$classtype[$q][$s]=$array['BookingClassFare']['classType'];        
            $z27=$farecode[$q][$s]=$array['BookingClassFare']['farebasiscode'];
            $z28=$rule[$q][$s]=mysql_real_escape_string($array['BookingClassFare']['Rule']);





                $mysql_query="insert into RviewInternationalFlight (q,s,FlightNumber,OperatingAirlineName,OperatingAirlineFlightNumber,OperatingAirlineCode,DepartureAirportName,DepartureAirportCode,ArrivalAirportName,ArrivalAirportCode,DepartureDateTime,ArrivalDateTime,ip,airequiptype,linksell,conx,airpchg,insideavailoption,gentrafrestriction,DaysOperates,JrnyTm,StartTerminal,EndTerminal,FltTm,LSAInd,Mile,availability,bookingclass,classtype,farecode,rule,basefare,tax,stax,tcharge,scharge,tdiscount,tmarkup,fid,fkey,totalfare,adultfare,adulttax,childfare,childtax,infantfare,infanttax,BIC,enddate,oaf,octax,numstops,tpc,tsdiscount) values('$q','$s','$z1','$z2','$z3','$z4','$z5','$z6','$z7','$z8','$z9','$z10','$ip','$z11','$z12','$z13','$z14','$z15','$z16','$z17','$z18','$z19','$z20','$z21','$z22','$z23','$z24','$z25','$z26','$z27','$z28','$f1','$f2','$f3','$f4','$f5','$f6','$f7','$f8','$f9','$ft','$a1','$a2','$c1','$c2','$i1','$i2','$z29','$z30','$z31','$f10','$z32','$f11','$f12')";

                mysql_query($mysql_query) or die(mysql_error());


    $s++;
    }
    $count[$q]=$s-1;


    $r=0;
    foreach($array_data['AvailResponse']['OriginDestinationOptions']['OriginDestinationOption'][$q]['Return']['FlightSegments']['FlightSegment'] as $array)
    {
            $z1=$rflightnumber[$q][$r]=$array['FlightNumber'];
            $z2=$rairlinename[$q][$r]=$array['OperatingAirlineName'];
            $z3=$rairlineflightnumber[$q][$r]=$array['OperatingAirlineFlightNumber'];
            $z4=$rairlinecode[$q][$r]=$array['OperatingAirlineCode'];
            $z5=$rdepartureloc[$q][$r]=$array['DepartureAirportName'];
            $z6=$rdeparturecode[$q][$r]=$array['DepartureAirportCode'];
            $z7=$rarrivalloc[$q][$r]=$array['ArrivalAirportName'];
            $z8=$rarrivalcode[$q][$r]=$array['ArrivalAirportCode'];
            $z9=$rdeparturetime[$q][$r]=$array['DepartureDateTime'];
            $z10=$rarrivaltime[$q][$r]=$array['ArrivalDateTime'];
            $z11=$rairequiptype[$q][$r]=$array['AirEquipType'];
            $z12=$rlinksell[$q][$r]=$array['LinkSellAgrmnt'];
            $z13=$rconx[$q][$r]=$array['Conx'];
            $z14=$rairpchg[$q][$r]=$array['AirpChg'];
            $z15=$rinsideavailoption[$q][$r]=$array['InsideAvailOption'];
            $z16=$rgentrafrestriction[$q][$r]=$array['GenTrafRestriction'];
            $z17=$rDaysOperates[$q][$r]=$array['DaysOperates'];

            $z30=$renddate[$q][$r]=$array['EndDt'];     
            $z31=$roaf[$q][$r]=$array['OperatingAirlineFlightNumber'];      
            $z32=$rnstops[$q][$r]=$array['NumStops'];       
            $z18=$rJrnyTm[$q][$r]=$array['JrnyTm'];     
            $z19=$rrtartTerminal[$q][$r]=$array['StartTerminal'];       
            $z20=$rEndTerminal[$q][$r]=$array['EndTerminal'];       
            $z21=$rFltTm[$q][$r]=$array['FltTm'];       
            $z22=$rLSAInd[$q][$r]=$array['LSAInd'];     
            $z23=$rMile[$q][$r]=$array['Mile'];

            $z24=$ravail[$q][$r]=$array['BookingClass']['Availability'];        
            $z29=$rbic[$q][$r]=$array['BookingClass']['BIC'];       
            $z25=$rbookingclass[$q][$r]=$array['BookingClassFare']['bookingclass'];     
            $z26=$rclasstype[$q][$r]=$array['BookingClassFare']['classType'];       
            $z27=$rfarecode[$q][$r]=$array['BookingClassFare']['farebasiscode'];
            $z28=$rrule[$q][$r]=mysql_real_escape_string($array['BookingClassFare']['Rule']);



                $mysql_query="insert into RviewInternationalFlight (q,r,FlightNumber,OperatingAirlineName,OperatingAirlineFlightNumber,OperatingAirlineCode,DepartureAirportName,DepartureAirportCode,ArrivalAirportName,ArrivalAirportCode,DepartureDateTime,ArrivalDateTime,ip,airequiptype,linksell,conx,airpchg,insideavailoption,gentrafrestriction,DaysOperates,JrnyTm,StartTerminal,EndTerminal,FltTm,LSAInd,Mile,availability,bookingclass,classtype,farecode,rule,basefare,tax,stax,tcharge,scharge,tdiscount,tmarkup,fid,fkey,totalfare,adultfare,adulttax,childfare,childtax,infantfare,infanttax,BIC,enddate,oaf,octax,numstops,tpc,tsdiscount) values('$q','$r','$z1','$z2','$z3','$z4','$z5','$z6','$z7','$z8','$z9','$z10','$ip','$z11','$z12','$z13','$z14','$z15','$z16','$z17','$z18','$z19','$z20','$z21','$z22','$z23','$z24','$z25','$z26','$z27','$z28','$f1','$f2','$f3','$f4','$f5','$f6','$f7','$f8','$f9','$ft','$a1','$a2','$c1','$c2','$i1','$i2','$z29','$z30','$z31','$f10','$z32','$f11','$f12')";

                mysql_query($mysql_query) or die(mysql_error());


    $r++;
    }
    $rcount[$q]=$r-1;

    $q++;
    }
```

The results are getting inserted in the Database.No problem upto here. But after inserting the results in database the page is getting stopped there and a blank page is displaying.

Why it is happening like that. Because of multiple loops..?? What may be the problem..?

Any suggestions..

Thanks.

Comment: It happens because of `max_execution_time` in your server.

Comment: Human-obfuscator in action

Comment: I'm not seeing any commands that result in any output in this script.. no output = blank page.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Ok fine..Can you please tell me how to increase the `max_execution_time` in server..?

Comment: @Orangepill Sry i did not understand your question clearly. ARe you asking that there is no code in the above question to display the result..?

Comment: @Sreeram put this at start of your page `ini_set ( 'max_execution_time', 1200);`, here `1200` is 1200 seconds. You can increase or decrease as you need.

Comment: Learn to use objective programming language features in PHP dude.

Comment: @Orangepill ACtually that is very long code.. Thats the reason i didnt provided you the code.

Comment: @Kamil Yes You are correct. I am working on that but not implimented in this code.

Comment: @zerkms Sry what u said. I didn't understand.

Comment: @Sreeram Have you tried the solution?